# Recutils: select with fallback

Tags: database, gnu

Given the fields in a `recfile`:

```
nickname: Jose
fullname_es: José Pérez
fullname: Jose Perez

...
```

how to select all fields with nickname, and if nickname doesn't exists, it fallsback to the Spanish name, and if it doesn't exist it falls back to the English one, and if it doesn't exist, it prints nothing.